# Intraclass correlation standard error

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, intraclass-correlation

I am in the last stage of my paper review and it is very close to getting submitted. However, there is a comment I am highly struggling with:

The reviewer wants to know what the **ICC and the s.e. of the ICC** is.

The model I have is a linear mixed effect model looking like:

```
mixedmodel <- lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | countries), weights=weight, Alldata)
```

Before I had never heard about the ICC. When looking for documentation, I do find information on ICC, but not on how to calculate the s.e. of the ICC.

Can anyone please help me with this? I am using R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get the ICC from the [sjstats-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjstats), which also offers bootstrapping. I would try bootstrapping to obtain se- and p-values (you can also take a look [at this discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2014q3/022654.html) in the r-sig-mailinglist for other approaches, but bootstrapping is one recommendation, two).

```
library(sjstats) # for ICC and bootstrapping
library(dplyr)   # for the pipe
library(lme4)

# compute ICC
fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
icc(fit)
> Linear mixed model
>  Family: gaussian (identity)
> Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)
>
>   ICC (Subject): 0.483090

# compute SE of ICC
dummy <- sleepstudy %>% 
  # generate 100 bootstrap replicates of dataset
  bootstrap(100) %>% 
  # run mixed effects regression on each bootstrap replicate
  mutate(models = lapply(.$strap, function(x) {
    lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), data = x)
  })) %>% 
  # compute ICC for each "bootstrapped" regression
  mutate(icc = unlist(lapply(.$models, icc)))

# now compute SE and p-values for the bootstrapped ICC
boot_se(dummy, icc)
>   term   std.err
> 1  icc 0.1024704

boot_p(dummy, icc)
>   term      p.value
> 1  icc 1.936526e-08
```

1. The above code takes the `sleepstudy` dataset and creates 100 bootstrap-samples, which are saved as "list-variable" named `strap`, in a new data frame.
2. This list-variable (i.e. the data frame with this variable), containing the 100 bootstrap-samples, is then "piped" into the `lapply`-command to run 100 `lmer`-commands (which are saved in another list-variable named `models`, see `mutate`-command).
3. This list-variable is then used to compute the ICC with the `sjstats::icc` function, so you have 100 ICC-values (for all models applied to the 100 bootstrap-samples) in the variable named `icc`.

Now `boot_se` and `boot_p` compute the standard error and p-value of any bootstrapped values, in this case the ICC-values.

Comment: Depending on your sample size, the computation of the mixed models for all bootstrap-samples may take _very_ much time. I have extended the `se()`-function in my _sjstats_-package, which now a) also accepts objects from the `icc()`-function, and b) prints a progress bar, so you can guess when the calculation is finished. I will commit the changes to GitHub (https://github.com/sjPlot/sjstats) tonight (in about 3-4 hours), so you may want to install the GitHub-version of sjstats and then, after fitting your model, simply run `se(icc(your_model))`.

Comment: I have over 60000 observations and the regression has 50 variables in Total. Nevertheless, it 'only' took about 30 minutes so I was very happy with it!